# Proof on irreducibility of the determinant polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

I just read the following proof of the fact that
a determinant polynomial is irreducible from [here](http://%20I%20just%20read%20the%20following%20proof%20of%20the%20fact%20that%20determinant%20polynomial%20is%20irreducible%20from%20here:%20%20Here%20is%20a%20proof%20using%20a%20little%20bit%20of%20algebraic%20geometry%20%20(we%20assume%20k%20is%20algebrically%20closed).%20It%20can%20be%20seen%20that%20%7B62f745cd-2f08-484f-9ade-9cf6b4333612%7D%20is%20irreducible%20in%20%7B59be0e37-0894-4ff7-a3fb-fb308ef1776e%7D.%20%20It%20is%20for%20example%20the%20image%20of%20the%20morphism%20%20%7Bdc0b543b-7bf8-4a2c-a597-e43a71442f29%7D,%20%7Bf1868195-0a73-4c5d-956a-6c7349b8dfa8%7D%20%20and%20the%20source%20is%20irreducible.%20%20Hence%20as%20%7B89cf43e2-6c8c-4c2b-861f-5841d70e834a%7D%20is%20a%20UFD%20we%20have%20%7B5e5bf5a5-53a1-4ebc-814c-8657d86fb1e7%7D%20%20where%20p%20is%20an%20irreducible%20polynomial.%20So%20%7B5aa4e214-495e-4505-a546-02aee63242ae%7D.%20%20To%20show%20that%20%7B3d2ac88a-669f-475c-b2fa-734f236610c2%7D%20we%20use%20the%20fact%20that%20the%20differential%20of%20the%20%20determinant%20at%20a%20matrice%20A%20is%20%7Bc2aa3b82-93c2-4fb9-9493-4fcc89ff9b7b%7D%20%20where%20Adj(A)%20is%20the%20adjugate%20matrix.%20For%20%7Bc658bdf8-ae70-465c-9238-1d03d5e834c3%7D%20such%20that%20%7B6b38e5ac-ed26-402a-b43a-10af30f2bd2d%7D%20%20we%20have%20%7Bab11b603-4df0-4c35-8943-f134f4a4fa57%7D%20so%20%7B06cfd335-c88a-423b-811d-0518104c44b8%7D%20which%20forces%20%7B5460ca05-c2e0-4887-93d1-62d9cd65b66c%7D.%20%20The%20argument%20from%20last%20part%20that%20shows%20that%20for%20%7B9a1f7285-eb60-43ab-9457-f3ba5e354601%7D%20the%20%20%7Bbde024db-f05f-4721-bae8-305707d6d645%7D%20equals%20%7B1f4b08a7-9f0f-4fbf-9a8e-d4810f7154f2%7D%20I%20not%20understand.%20%20%20In%20the%20answer%20we%20choose%20a%20%7B7aa30015-f939-4d75-87fe-21e561acc2a2%7D%20matrix%20%7B13e86a8c-9815-4bd1-9029-93669b518fa0%7D%20with%20rank%20%7B1c2ed106-0623-415d-86b3-745726afa747%7D%20and%20observe%20that%20%20%7B3f0d6d89-6c5d-4916-8720-829cb8410364%7D.%20%20Well,%20why%20this%20implies%20%7B3edd5ac8-35fd-4d07-98b7-690b3127d76b%7D%20and%20why%20this%20foces%20%7Ba2442121-ad1a-40ff-b8ff-c0b267226f8a%7D%20to%20be%20%7B263a1ccb-5ec9-4995-b8af-8975dfd84098%7D?):

> Here is a proof using a little bit of algebraic geometry
> (we assume k is algebraically closed).
> It can be seen that $V(det)$ is irreducible in $k^{n^2}$.
> It is for example the image of the morphism
> $M_n(k)\times M_n(k) \rightarrow V(det)$, $(P,Q)\mapsto PI_{n-1}Q$
> and the source is irreducible.

> Hence as $k[X_{ij}]$ is a UFD we have $I(V(det)) = \sqrt{(p)}$
> where p is an irreducible polynomial. So $det = p^k$.

> To show that $k=1$ we use the fact that the differential of the
> determinant at a matrice A is $D(det)_A(.) = Tr(Adj(A).)$
> where Adj(A) is the adjugate matrix. For $A$ such that $rk(A)=n-1$
> we have $rk(Adj(A))=1$ so $D(det)_A(.)\neq 0$ (e.g. what about nonzero nilpotent matrices) which forces $k=1$.

The argument from the last part that shows that for $det = p^k$ the
$k$ equals $1$ I do not understand.

In the answer we choose a $n \times n$ matrix $A$ with rank $n-1$ and observe that
$rk(Adj(A))=1$.

Well, why this implies $Tr(Adj(A).) \neq 0$ and
why this forces $k$ to be $1$?

Comment: $Adj(A)$ has positive rank so is nonzero, thus $Tr(Adj(A) \cdot ) \neq 0$ (that’s elementary – a nice exercise if you don’t know it). If $\det=p^k$, then, for any matrix $B$, $\det(A+tB)=p^k(A+tB)$ so (at $t=0$) $\frac{d}{dt}\det(A+tB)=Tr(Adj(A)B)$, so is nonzero for a suitable choice of $B$. But at $t=0$, $\frac{d}{dt}\det(A+tB)=\frac{d}{dt}p^k(A+tB)=kp^{k-1}(A)(d_Ap)(B)=0$ if $k > 1$. So $k=1$.

Comment: the last consequence I not understand. why $kp^{k-1}(A)(d_Ap)(B)=0$ if $k >1$?

Comment: Because $p^k(A)=\det(A)=0$ so $p(A)=0$. If $k > 1$ then $p^{k-1}(A)$ is nontrivial. That's the same reason why the derivative of $x^n$ at $x=0$ vanishes for $n > 1$ but not for $n=1$.

Comment: Let me clarify a point. When you write $p^k(A)$ you regard it
as product, i.e. $k$-times $p^k(A) = p(A) \cdot p(A) \cdot ... \cdot p(A)$
with "$\cdot$" = multiplication in field $k$, right?

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant. That’s also what is meant by $p^k=\det$.